# All build submissions in a build must use project instances originating from the same project collection

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to publish a .NET project in VS-2017. When I publish I get the error:

> All build submissions in a build must use project instances originating from the same project collection.

The project builds fine in both release and debug mode. The same thing happens when trying to publish as debug. Any ideas how I can get more information on what is wrong?

Comment: I am having the same issue a workaround we are using at the minute is to publish in debug instead of release not the best bit of advice but does as a workaround

Answer (score 1):

For me help to build and publish my solution via msbuild.
you should create a publish profile in visual studio, before run msbuild.

open cmd
and run the next command:

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin" d:\VMC\VMC.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="FolderProfile"

also you should replace path to msbuid(if it is different on you computer) and solution.

For me it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly to answer your question, the way to get more information would be to go to the MS Dev community (try here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18721/all-build-submissions-in-a-build-must-use-project-1.html).

I had this error I think because my .net Core solution included a framework 4.5.2 project. I individually rebuilt each project in release mode first and the publish subsequently worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped to delete the .xproj file from the project folder and set the platform target of the project to publish to x86

Answer (score 0):

The VS2017 project that I previously published, gave the same error and taking these steps solved the issue for me:

- Tried to publish in Debug (did not resolve)
- Deleted obj folder (did not resolve)
- Manually deleted files in target path (did not resolve)
- Ran VS as Admin (did not resolve)
- Cleaned solution (RESOLVED).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have seen to this is to update to VS 2017 15.5.2 or greater.  This was a VS bug.  Rather than using workarounds just upgrade.

Here is a current update link: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/